# runining a crawler from command line gives an error

Tags: import.io

When i try to run the crawler from the cmd it gives this error

```
Error: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
Unexpected end-of-input in field name at 
[Source: java.io.FileInputStream@19f6368; line: 2, column: 2]
```

and the code im using

```
import.ioc.exe -crawl C:\Users\~\Desktop\importCMD\crawler.json C:\Users\~\Desktop\importCMD\auth.json
```

i have tried running as Admin still didnt work "Win8 / 64bit" and using the latest version of import.io

Auth json

```
{
"userGuid": "88f4ec3c97154c----b833fb4cd9fe0",
"apiKey": "88f4ec3c97154c46829b833----------9badfe87c502e8dc0298d153c4433c577d083afdbfbe8df13d66ec762c5a102edcd849a36b1879b5f0f73787a1f99531c9b66679"
```

}

crawler json

```
    {  
   "cookiesEnabled":false,
   "robotsDisabled":false,
   "canonicalDisabled":false,
   "outputFile":"C:\\Users\\~\\Desktop\\import.io CMD\\cmd - test.csv",
   "advancedMode":true,
   "connections":3,
   "connectorGuid":"dfb05194-0000-4bbe-b990-302c65875754",
   "pause":1,
   "crawlTemplate":[  
      "https://www.website.com/"
   ],
   "dataTemplate":[  
      "https://www.website.com/{any}/link"
   ],
   "destination":"CSV",
   "maxDepth":0,
   "startUrls":[  
      "https://www.website.com/products/link1",
      "https://www.website.com/products/link2",
      "https://www.website.com/products/link3",
      "https://www.website.com/products/link4",
      "https://www.website.com/products/link5",
      "https://www.website.com/products/link6"
   ],
   "local":false
}
```

Comment: Show the json files...

Comment: @Marged i edited the question with json files

Comment: Perhaps there are other JSON files that get used without you knowing. Increase the loglevel, especially that of Jackson and see if you get details which file and which exact line is the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same issue. My platform is windows 7.

If you copy the auth.json from import.io knowledge base (http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/325728-command-line-crawling), there is a U+FEFF character in the head of second line.

remove it and you can run the crawler in windows.

Comment: the character <feff> (I found it by open the file in VIM)

Comment: i didn't see that character but i removed the spaces and it worked , Thanks alot man

Answer (score 2):

a `JsonParseException` is mostly likely due to something being wrong in the json files you are supplying in `crawler.json` or `auth.json`

try pasting the contents of those files into [this website](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) and pressing the tick box in the top right hand side of the page, if the json has errors. It will tell you where they are.

Comment: i validated them and there was nothing wrong , event tried the auth.json with quotes/double qoutes / dashed same error always